# Tensorflow VGG16 (converted from caffe) got low evaluation accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I didn't convert the weights by myself, instead I used vgg16_weights.npz from www(dot)cs(dot)toronto(dot)edu/~frossard/post/vgg16/. There, it is mentioned

> We convert the Caffe weights publicly available in the author’s GitHub profile (gist(dot)github(dot)com/ksimonyan/211839e770f7b538e2d8#file-readme-md) using a specialized tool (github(dot)com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow).

But, in that page, there is no validation code, so I made it referring to tensorflow [MNIST](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist) and [inception](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception) code.

**How I create TFRecords of Imagenet**

I use build_imagenet_data.py from inception. I changed the

> label_index = 0 #originally label_index = 1

because inception use label_index 0 as background class (so in total there are 1001 classes). Caffe format doesn't use that as the number of output is 1000. I prefer to use TFRecord format as I will change process the weight and retrain.

**How I load the weights**

inference function taken from MNIST's mnist.py was modified so the Variable is taken from the vgg16_weights.npz

How I load the weights:

```
weights = np.load('/the_path/vgg16_weights.npz')
```

How I put the variable in conv1_1:

```
with tf.name_scope('conv1_1') as scope:
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.constant(weights['conv1_1_W']), name='weights')
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(weights['conv1_1_b']), name='biases')

    out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
    sess.run(conv1_1)
```

**How I read the TFRecords**

I took inception's image_processing.py, dataset.py, and ImagenetData.py with no change. Then, I run inception's inception_eval.py evaluate function with changing in inference code and deleting the restoring moving variable from checkpoint (as I already restore manually in variable initialization). However, the accuracy is not same with the VGG-16 in caffe. Top-5 accuracy is around 9%.

**Closing**

What is the problem of this method? There are several part of code that I still don't understand though:

1. How TFReader move to the next batch of images after processing 1 batch of images? The output of inception's image_processing.py size is only the number of batch size. To be complete, this is the output based on documentation:

> images: Images. 4D tensor of size [batch_size, FLAGS.image_size,
>                                          image_size, 3].
>
> labels: 1-D integer Tensor of [FLAGS.batch_size].

2. Do I need softmax the logits before tf.in_top_k ? (Well, I don't think it is matter as the value sequence is same)

Thank you for the help. Sorry if the link is messy as I can only post 2 links in 1 post because of my reputation.

**UPDATE**

I tried myself by changing the caffe weight. Reverse the channel input dimension of conv1_1 (because caffe receive BGR, so the weight is for BGR instead of RGB in tensorflow) and get the same accuracy with the weight from website: around 9% in top-5.

I found out that there is no mean image subtraction in tensorflow inception's image_processing.py. I add mean subtraction (in eval_image function) with tf.reduce_mean and got 11% accuracy.

Then I tried to change the eval_image function with

```
# source: https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow/blob/master/examples/imagenet/dataset.py
img_shape = tf.to_float(tf.shape(image)[:2])
min_length = tf.minimum(img_shape[0], img_shape[1])
new_shape = tf.to_int32((256 / min_length) * img_shape) #isotropic case

# new_shape = tf.pack([256,256]) #non isotropic case

image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [new_shape[0], new_shape[1]])

offset = tf.to_int32((new_shape - 224) / 2)
image = tf.slice(image, begin=tf.pack([offset[0], offset[1], 0]), size=tf.pack([224, 224, -1]))

# mean_subs_image = tf.reduce_mean(image,axis=[0,1],keep_dims=True)

return image - mean_subs_image
```

and I got 13%. Increased but still lack a lot. Seems it is one of the problem. I am not sure what is the other problems.

Answer (score 0):

In general porting whole model weights across libraries will be hard. You pointed out some differences from caffe, but there could be others. It might be easier to retrain the model in TensorFlow.